# Select a subcategory ID to associate with a primary ID based off which has the highest sum

Tags: sql, subquery, max, vertica

I have a primary ID, ID1, and a secondary ID, ID2. ID1 can be associated with multiple ID2 values, and vice versa. I want to sum a third Values column by ID2 under each ID1, and pull the ID2 with the highest sum. The source data is structured like:

```
ID1     ID2     Value
1       10      1
1       10      2
1       20      1
2       10      1
2       30      2
```

And I want the final results to look like:

```
ID1     ID2
1       10
2       30
```

So far, I only have a nonfunctioning query:

```
SELECT  ID1,
        CASE    WHEN ID2_Value = MAX(ID2_Value) THEN ID2
                ELSE NULL
                END AS PrimaryID2
FROM (  SELECT  ID1,
                ID2,
                SUM(Value) AS ID2_Value
        FROM SOME_SCHEMA
        GROUP BY ID1, ID2
       ) AS ID2_Value
GROUP BY ID1;
```

My query doesn't work right now because it expects me to include ID2_Value in the `GROUP BY` statement, but I don't want to group by those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `row_number()`:

```
select id1, id2
from (select id1, id2, sum(value) as sumv,
             row_number() over (partition by id1 order by sum(value) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id1, id2
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```